# How to make object rotate from the base in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

Im trying to make a flamethrower in unity and I intend for the hitbox to just be a rectangle being pointed towards the cursor. I got it to follow the cursor but it rotates from the center and not from the end like I want[image]

What I am looking for is for the box to rotate from this base

[image]

I set the box as a parent of the gun the player holds to keep its position locked but that did not change the fact that it rotates from the center.

Comment: You're far more likely to get a response to this on the GameDev stack exchange site. That said, as a general rule, if you want to change the origin [rotation point] of an object, add a parent object and offset the child by an appropriate amount, then rotate the parent.

Comment: Rotation is always done from the point of origin. For the default box it is in the center, since that's what is usually needed. It's also possible to model a new box (flamethrower) that has the origin at the spot that you want to rotate, but @Basic 's suggestion is the go to, since it is much easier to maintain when you change your mind later.